# MongoDB information request

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm setting up a data base in MongoDB. I have two models called companies and users.

```
const companySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  users: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: false,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true },
  password: String,
  company: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: false,
    ref: 'Company'
  }
})
```

When I want to get users from a specific company. I see two options. Query by company to users database, or query to companies database and get all users references from that company. I guess the bigger the users database is, the less efficient is the first option. is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Your above implementation is correct. If you want to users from specific company you need to query like this:

```
const User = require('./modules/user/userSchema');
const { ObjectId } = require('mongoose').Types;

userCtr.getCompany = (req, res) => {
    const { companyId } = req.body;

    User.find({ company: ObjectId(companyId) }).populate({
            path: 'company',
            select: 'name'
        })
        .then((data) => {
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.send(500).json(err);
        });
 }
```

It's gives you all `users` which have `requested company`.

Comment: my question is: isn't it better to query like this
Company.find({name: company_name}).populate('users')?? If we had a big database isn't it faster? Otherwise which sense make the references?

Comment: Yaa u can use this approach for getting faster results.